# Using a constant inside of a service - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use two constants inside a service, but the constants are undefined. I also included these constants in different controllers and there isn't the problem with undefined variables. Why is this the case?

```
var app = angular.module("angularJsApplication", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/overview", {
            ...
        });
});


app.constant('user1Constant', "aa");
app.constant('user2Constant', "bb");


app.factory("databaseService", [function (user1Constant, user2Constant) {
    console.log(user1Constant); //user1Constant is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory Should be like this,

```
app.factory("databaseService", ["user1Constant","user2Constant", function(user1Constant,user2Constant) {
console.log(user1Constant);
}
```